# Can I Sort sub-array by its value alphabetically in php?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, alphabetical, sub-array

I have $mainArr array and I want result as $resultArr.

```
$mainArr = array(
            0 => array(125 => 'B', 127 => 'A', 178 => 'Z', 78 => 'G'),
            1 => array(111 => 'X', 127 => 'K', 108 => 'J', 708 => 'P'),
            2 => array(125 => 'L', 127 => 'M', 178 => 'Q', 78 => 'A'),
    );
```

I want result like below:

```
$resultArr = array(
        0 => array(127 => 'A', 125 => 'B', 78 => 'G', 178 => 'Z', ),
        1 => array(108 => 'J', 127 => 'K', 708 => 'P', 111 => 'X',),
        2 => array(78 => 'A', 125 => 'L', 127 => 'M', 178 => 'Q'),
    );
```

Comment: I have used different php sort function, but I couldn't found solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_map function to sort multi dimensional arrays.

To sort your above array, you can use something like this,

```
function sortArr($a) {
    natsort($a);
    return $a;
}

$mainArr = array(0 => array(125 => 'B', 127 => 'A', 178 => 'Z', 78 => 'G'),
            1 => array(111 => 'X', 127 => 'K', 108 => 'J', 708 => 'P'),
            2 => array(125 => 'L', 127 => 'M', 178 => 'Q', 78 => 'A'),
    );

$sortedArr = array_map( "sortArr", $mainArr);
```

It will give below output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [127] => A
            [125] => B
            [78] => G
            [178] => Z
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [108] => J
            [127] => K
            [708] => P
            [111] => X
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [78] => A
            [125] => L
            [127] => M
            [178] => Q
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mainArr = array_map( function( $a ){
    uksort( $a, function( $b, $c ) use( $a ){
        return $a[$b] > $a[$c];
    });
    return $a;
}, $mainArr );
```

Comment: It sorts by value, maintaining key association, just like they wanted.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it works and why you feel it is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/2723382) on StackOverflow that seems to be just what you're looking for: sorting a multi-dimensional array in PHP. It requires defining a custom comparison function and passing it (and the array you wish to sort) as arguments to [uasort](http://php.net/uasort), which maintains the association between key-value pairs. Note: since you want to sort each row, you would probably sort each row, like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a, $b); // also look into strnatcmp()

function sortArray($mainArr) {
    $resultArr = array();
    foreach (array $arr in $mainArr)
        $resultArr[] = uasort($arr, 'cmp'); // append the new row to $resultArr
    return $resultArr;
}
```

For future reference, it's useful to google extensively (a skill worth learning, especially in this field) before asking your question (as Burak mentioned). This way, people can provide more effective feedback and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, its a bit mandraulic but its easy to understand

```
$resultArr = array();

foreach ( $mainArr as $sortme ) {
    asort($sortme);
    $resultArr[] = $sortme;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk()` to traverse the first level and modify the subarrays  by reference with`&`, then call `asort()` on each subarray to sort alphabetically while preserving the original keys.

No `return` is necessary because all modifications are applied directly on the input variable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/h8K3a))

```
$mainArr = [
    [125 => 'B', 127 => 'A', 178 => 'Z', 78 => 'G'],
    [111 => 'X', 127 => 'K', 108 => 'J', 708 => 'P'],
    [125 => 'L', 127 => 'M', 178 => 'Q', 78 => 'A'],
];

array_walk($mainArr, function(&$subarray) {
    asort($subarray);
});

var_export($mainArr);
```

Or the more concise equivalent technique using PHP7.4's arrow function syntax (the return value provided my the magic `=>` is silently disregarded by `array_walk()`): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/g615r))

```
array_walk($mainArr, fn(&$subarray) => asort($subarray));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    127 => 'A',
    125 => 'B',
    78 => 'G',
    178 => 'Z',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    108 => 'J',
    127 => 'K',
    708 => 'P',
    111 => 'X',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    78 => 'A',
    125 => 'L',
    127 => 'M',
    178 => 'Q',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can.

You can do it like this:

```
$resultArr = [];
foreach ($mainArr as $m){
    asort($m);
    $resultArr[] = $m;
}
var_dump($resultArr);
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: You might want to test that

Comment: There is no benefit to fixing an incorrect answer to become a duplicate solution on the same page.